# Как передать два JSON-объекта одновременно

Tags: php, jquery

В общем есть код и нужно принять результат этого кода в jQuery, но проблема в том что они должны приниматься вместе.

```
if ($Territory)
{
  $rayons=$Hint->qualiRayons($Territory) ;
    echo json_encode($rayons);
}

if($Rayons and $hintingTerrytory!=='80' and $hintingTerrytory!=='85' and $notRayonsTowns!=1)
{
   $towns=$Hint->qualiTawns($Territory, $Rayons);
    echo json_encode($towns);
}
```

есть два цикла для перебора массива

```
for (var key in data){
                    optionRayons+= '<option value="'+data[key]+'">'+data[key]+'</option>';
                }



for (var town in data) {
                    optionTowns += '<option value="' + data[town] + '">' + data[town] + '</option>'
                }
```

в общем передаю я по сути два массива datа, а это ответ сервака, так вот вопрос, как закодировать на стороне PHP json чтобы принять их корректно для обработки. в Jquery?

Comment: клади в один объект с разными именами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

код конечно тот еще, но судя по всему нужно это:

```
$response = [];
if ($Territory) {      
    $response['rayons'] = $Hint->qualiRayons($Territory);        
}

if($Rayons and $hintingTerrytory!=='80' and $hintingTerrytory!=='85' and $notRayonsTowns!=1) {
   $response['towns'] = $Hint->qualiTawns($Territory, $Rayons);        
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

в ответе они будут лежать в `data.rayons` и `data.towns`